# fopen( $myFile, "r" ) why I got return NULL

Tags: php, file

```
$fp = fopen( $myFile, "r" );

//if echo $fp => I GOT NULL 

fclose($fp);
```

But if I do `file_get_contents($myFile);` I got the string data of that file.

My file ( fedora os )

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 apache appli 104  2 nov.  12:54 12_62_xxx.log
```

Comment: have you got permission on that file?

Comment: yes becuase when file_get_contents($myFile) I got the file content.

Comment: Use `var_dump` instead of `echo` to find out what `$fp` really is: `var_dump($fp)`;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$fp` is a handle, it's not some real data from the file. You can use this handle in other funcitons, such as `fread` or `fclose`.
`file_get_contents` internally opens the file, reads it, closes the file and returns the string. That's why when you print the result of the last one you get the file's contents.

Try `echo fgets($fp)` and see what you get.

Comment: +1 but they should still see something like `Resource id #n` when echoing `$fp`